# How to limit number of string values in API endpoint using Python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, api, generator

*Here, in the code. I can only use 5 values maximum(API limitation) at a time in the below API.*

```
import requests
import json
import datetime
from datetime import date, datetime
import itertools
from sentimeterdb import dbconnect

from dotenv import load_dotenv   #for python-dotenv method
load_dotenv()                    #for python-dotenv method

import os

#Connection string pointing to the PROD db.
dbclient = dbconnect.process()
db = dbclient.abc
co_open = db.open_ab

myquery = {"bugs" : {"$ne" : {}, "$exists": True}}
mydoc = co_open.find(myquery)

lst = []
for x in mydoc:
    y = x.get('bugs')
    id_list = lst.append([*y.values()])
    cdets = list(itertools.chain(*lst))

cdets_split = cdets
string_cdets = ','.join(cdets_split[:5])

Access_URL = 'https://generating-token-from--here/oauth2/default/v1/token'

client_id = os.environ.get('CLIENT_ID')
client_secret = os.environ.get('CLIENT_SECRET')
grant_type = os.environ.get('GRANT_TYPE')
BASE_URL = f'https://google.com/{string_cdets}'

response = requests.post(Access_URL,
                     data={'grant_type': grant_type, 'client_id': client_id, 'client_secret': client_secret, 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
json_response = response.json()

tokenvalue = (json_response['access_token'])

headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +
       tokenvalue, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

auth_response = requests.get(BASE_URL,  headers=headers)
auth_response_json = auth_response.json()

severity_list = []
for severity_5 in auth_response_json['bugs']:
    severity_list.append([severity_5['severity']])

print ("Severity ==> ", severity_list)
```

Severity and Status should be given for all the CDETs. Currently, It is only giving for 5 items.
how can I get the response of all the CDETs?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I get the question, but using a generator does not affect the complexity at all. A `for` loop is perfectly fine.

A generator would be useful, if the values ('ABC', 'DEF' etc.) were generated on-the-fly. In that case, you could use a `for` loop to cycle over the generator.

Comment: Even If I use for loop, can you demonstrate how it is possible using the date I provided ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a recipe shown in the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) documentation for a function called `batched` which can be used to yield "chunks" of an arbitrary size from an iterable

```
from itertools import islice 


def batched(iterable, n):
    "Batch data into tuples of length n. The last batch may be shorter."
    # batched('ABCDEFG', 3) --> ABC DEF G
    if n < 1:
        raise ValueError('n must be at least one')
    it = iter(iterable)
    while batch := tuple(islice(it, n)):
        yield batch
```

The [answer given here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/312464/8512262) might also be useful.

At any rate, as you've already guessed, you'll end up passing these chunks into a `for` loop to make your API call(s).

```
for group in batched(values, 5):
    ...  # insert API call here
```

I'm not sure of a way you can do this *without* multiple API calls. Taking the approach of chunking the list like this inherently means you'll have to make the call until your list is exhausted.

---

**EDIT:** following updates from OP

If what's changing is the value of `BASE_URL`, you would simply loop over your "batches" from `cdets`, updating `BASE_URL` as needed and passing that to `requests.get(BASE_URL,  headers=headers)`

```
auth_responses = []  # init an empty list to store responses


for batch in batched(cdets, 5):
    string_cdets = ','.join(batch)
    BASE_URL = f'https://google.com/{string_cdets}'
    # append responses to the list
    auth_responses.extend(requests.get(BASE_URL, headers=headers))
```

*Caveat* - there's a bit of guesswork done here since we have no idea what these CDETs are...

Also FWIW, `BASE_URL` should really be styled as `base_url` since it's a variable whose value changes - all caps is typically used to imply a `CONSTANT` value, which `BASE_URL` definitely isn't

Comment: Can you demonstrate the code with API call as well, I am little confuse with the appropriate data type which API requires. Ex;- api = https://www.google.com/ABC,DEF,GHI,JKL,MNO

Comment: You'll have to edit your question to include the code you use for the API calls. As it stands, all `api = https://www.google.com/{val}` is doing is formatting a string. And without knowing what API you're using, we can't help much.

Comment: Just edited the question for better understanding. Let me know If anything is not clear.

Comment: See update - I hope that helps, as I can't really test it on my end